# How can i change the error message in Firebase? For example, when invalid password is entered?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image: Error Message]

How can i change the error message? I would like to find a way to customise this error message

This is my sign in method

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({ type: “LOGIN”, payload: res.user });
    setIsPending(false);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    setError(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to *change* the error message that Firebase returns, but you can check the error code and then show you own message based on that.

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({ type: “LOGIN”, payload: res.user });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.code === "auth/") {
      setError("The password you entered does not match to this user.");
    }
    else {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setIsPending(false);
  });
```

See the full [list of error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes) to learn what you might want to handle.

Comment: It's also good style to reset/clear any loading/pending state in the sad-path. Doing so in a `.finally` from the Promise chain is a good **DRY** place for it.

Comment: Good point @DrewReese, I didn't even notice that. .   I modified the code in my answer to use `finally` for clearing that state.